Remove auto format and autofix from ZLS COMPLETELY (with nvim kickstart)
ZLS version is for 0.12.0 (I put in into PATH and lua script and checked if some plugin puts builtin LSP which I dont need).
In config_gen/config.json:
        {
            "name": "enable_autofix",
            "description": "Whether to automatically fix errors on save. Currently supports adding and removing discards.",
            "type": "bool",
            "default": false
        },

And it still compresses my struct into a single line:
//before
const Container = struct {
    childs: std.ArrayList(),
    content: []u8
};

//after saving
const Container = struct { childs: std.ArrayList(), content: []u8 };

I tried to configure it in init.lua (I installed kickstart and did almost no changes):
        zls = {
          cmd = { 'C:/zig/lsp/1.12.0/zig-out/bin/zls.exe' },
          settings = {
            Lua = {
              format_on_save = false,
            },
          },
        },

And copypasted in Autoformat section right after lua's formater
It is better if I fix it not only for nvim, but in ZLS config or whatever

You're missing a comma after the last field. See this for an explanation.

If you would like to keep a multiline struct with zig fmt, you can put a comma after the last field: struct { content: []u8, } will become multiline on save. I'm not sure how to disable format on save in your editor, although zls does have its own config file that can be put in the project root that should work.

If you also put a comma in the last line, the formatting will be implemented accordingly:
const Container = struct {
    childs: std.ArrayList(),
    content: []u8,
};

This also applies, for example, to parameters in functions, etc.:
fn foo(
    p1: u8,
    p2: u8,
    p3: u8,
) void {

